# vuex erro: [vuex] unknown action type

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Preciso separar as responsabilidades do meu store (vuex) de UM arquivo para dois(services e store); O problema é que independente de como eu faça mesmo utilizando outros exemplos ele sempre retorna o erro:

```
[vuex] unknown action type: loadApiCards
```

Pesquisei bastante no google e não sei dizer o que estou fazendo errado.

AppsServices.js

```
    import axios from 'axios'
import {
  BaseURL,
  URL
} from './Apps.mappers'

export const loadApiCards = () => {
  return axios.get(`${BaseURL}/${URL}`)
    .then(result => result.data.apps)
    .catch(error => {
      throw new Error(`API ${error}`)
    })
}
```

store.js

```
actions: {
    loadCards ({ commit }) {
      AppsService.loadApiCards()
        .then(apiCards => commit('APP_CARDS ', apiCards)
        )
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    APP_CARDS (state, apiCards) {
      console.log('work')
      state.apiCards = apiCards
      this.apiCards = state.apiCards
      this.apiCards = addIcon(apiCards)

      function addIcon (element) {
        element.map((card, i) => {
          if (card.id === state.apiIconsCards[i].id) {
            card.icon = state.apiIconsCards[i].icon
          }
        })
      }
    },
```

O arquivo Home.vue

```
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
import Banner from '@/components/Banner.vue'
import FilterSelect from '@/components/FilterSelect.vue'
export default {
  name: 'Home',
  components: {
    Banner,
    FilterSelect
  },
   computed: mapState(['apiCards']),
   created () {
     this.$store.dispatch('loadApiCards')
   }
}
```

O antigo arquivo store.js que estava funcionando:

```
Vue.axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://demo3241810.mockable.io/'

actions: {
     loadApiCards ({
       commit
     }) {
       Vue.axios.get('apps').then(result => {
         commit('APP_CARDS', result.data.apps)
       }).catch(error => {
         throw new Error(`API ${error}`)
       })
     },
   mutations: {
     APP_CARDS (state, apiCards) {
       state.apiCards = apiCards
       this.apiCards = state.apiCards
       this.apiCards = addIcon(apiCards)

       function addIcon (element) {
         element.map((card, i) => {
          if (card.id === state.apiIconsCards[i].id) {
             card.icon = state.apiIconsCards[i].icon
           }
         })
       }
     },
```

Comment: Podes partilhar a store completa? ou seja onde tens `new Vuex.Store({`

Comment: É que ela estava muito gigante.. mas ela ta aqui ó: O antigo: https://github.com/lauragrassig/up-vue-teste/blob/master/src/store/store.js  
o novo: 
https://github.com/lauragrassig/up-vue-teste/blob/master/src/services/Vuex.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme as mudanças que você fez a sua nova action é *loadCards* e não *loadApiCards*.

Tenta trocar o nome da chamada da sua action assim:

```
this.$store.dispatch('loadCards');
```

Comment: NOSSA, MUITO obrigada! Realmente eu nem tinha reparado nisso... que erro bobo mds